# Add data from a dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, append

I'd like to add data from a dataframe to a another dataframe.

Here my first data frame: df

[image]

Here my second dataframe: dff

[image]

```
df.append(dff, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

And it results me that:

[image]

Comment: `df.combine_first(dff)` ??

Comment: try `df.merge(dff, on='Postal Code')`, or it has to be added based on other logic?

Comment: in fact only `df.merge(dff)` should be sufficient, since `Postal Code` is the only common column

Comment: try result = pd.concat([df, dff], ignore_index=True, sort=False)

Comment: Please DO NOT post samples in images, it is always recommended to post samples as a text with CODE TAGS @Info Digitalevo kindly edit your post and do let us know then.

Answer (score 3):

Appending is adding two dataframe 'on top of each other' so you add rows. If you want to add new columns to your dataframe from another dataframe, you use `join` or `merge` especially if you have a `key column` where you can merge, which is in your case `Postal Code`

In pandas we use `pd.merge` for merging two dataframes with each other like the followng:

```
df_final = pd.merge(df, dff, on='Postal Code')


    Postal Code     Borough     Neighbourhood   Lattitude   Longitude
0   M1B             Scarborough Rouge           43.806686   -79.194353
1   M1B             Scarborough Malvern         43.806686   -79.194353
2   M1C             Scarborough Port Union      43.784535   -79.160497
3   M1C             Scarborough Rouge Hill      43.784535   -79.160497
4   M1C             Scarborough Highland Creek  43.784535   -79.160497
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is what you're looking for.

```
df.merge(dff, on='Postal Code')
```

should do the trick.